# Something wrong with my linear regression code

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

Now i'm studying Linear regression with python(tensorflow),  I referred to some tutorial, and made a below code.

so this Linear code could expect next result (W = 2, b = 2)

But if I expand the feed data, the result is broken.

ex) 3 -> 5

x_data = [1,2,3,4,5]

y_data = [4,6,8,10,12]

Rank is still 1,

and in shape, each X and Y are expanded by plus 2

I expected more data make a increase accuracy, but the result looks something wrong.

Why that code is valid only next condition

x_data = [1,2,3] y_data = [4,6,8]

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = [1,2,3]
y_data = [4,6,8]

# Try to find values for W and b that compute y_data = W*x_data + b
# (We know that W should be 1 and b 0, but tf will
# figure that out for us )

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -10.0, 10.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -10.0, 10.0))

##### 추가 및 변경된 부분 #####

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

hypothesis = W * X + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))

# Minimize
a = tf.Variable(0.1) # Learning rate, alpha
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(a)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

# Before starting, initialize the variables.
# Lets run
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Fit the line
for step in range(2001):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={X:x_data, Y:y_data})
    if step % 20 == 0:
        print (step, sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:x_data, Y:y_data}), sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

Comment: You've said the results look wrong, but you haven't included your actual results - could you do that? Is it nan values for the parameters (I can reproduce this)?

Answer (score 0):

Running your script with [1,2,3,4,5] and [4,6,8,10,12], I see that the optimization diverges and produces "nan" values for W and b; I'll assume this is the issue you mean by the result being "broken."

The main two problems are that that your step size (alpha = 0.1) is very aggressive and that the default initialization for the parameters W and B are probably not optimal. This is always a context-dependent evaluation --- there's no universal setting of alpha that's appropriate for every optimization problem --- so you should look at the convergence steps. Modifying your script to print the values after each iteration, here are the first few:

`ORIGINAL VALUES:
(-1, 1046.1516, array([-5.939405], dtype=float32), array([-4.5157075], dtype=float32))
OPTIMIZING
(0, 1949.8801, array([15.435911], dtype=float32), array([1.5510774], dtype=float32))
(1, 3636.85, array([-13.854544], dtype=float32), array([-6.420686], dtype=float32))
(2, 6785.708, array([26.077063], dtype=float32), array([4.7761774], dtype=float32))`

See how big the variations in the parameters are? Values for the parameters end up changing by large fractional amounts --- up to 350%! The gradient of the least squares cost in this one-dimensional case for the parameter W is

`D[cost]/D[W] = 2W/N * sum_i (W x_i + B - y_i)`

or equivalently

`1/W D[cost]/D[W] = 2 (W <x> + B - <y>)`

So, the initial error (`W <x> + B - <y>`) from the initial random values of W and B (-5.9 and -4.5) is equal to -35 --- and alpha being 0.1, the parameter W will be changed by a fractional amount of about -350% (100% * -35 * 0.1). That's why W goes from -5.9 all the way up to 15.4.

So, the two problems are:
- the initial values of W and B seem to be large. You might want to try a different initialization mechanism. I don't know off hand what the recommended procedure is, but maybe the tf.global_variables_initializer isn't the best in this case
- more importantly, your learning parameter alpha is too large. Try a smaller value like 0.001; or try 0.1 with an AdamOptimizer instead of a GradientDescentOptimizer. The AdamOptimizer should deal better with the big fluctuations you see with W going from -5.9 => 15.4 => -13.8 => 26.1 and so on.

Comment: i don't now how i can express my thanks. I really appreciate on your kind answer. it was really helpful to me